# PHPUnit not doing anything, no output

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have written some test cases and want to try them out with PHPUnit. However, it does not work.
If I run `phpunit CategoryTest` it outputs:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

If I do `phpunit --log-json error.log CategoryTest`, error.log file displays:

```
{"event":"suiteStart","suite":"CategoryTest","tests":5}  
{"event":"testStart","suite":"CategoryTest","test":"CategoryTest::test__construct"}
```

So, it finds that there are 5 tests in the file, starts doing the first one and for no reason stops. Is there any log where I could find a reason why it would not continue execution?
Also, if I run test on some other file, say `phpunit --log-json error.log UserTest`, the shell does not display any output and neither does error.log file.

I tried reinstalling it, as it was suggested in one of the other similar questions, but it didn't do anything.

Any ideas how I could fix it?

```
require_once '../Category.class.php';
require_once '../../db_connect.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';

class CategoryTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

private $Category;

protected function setUp() {

    parent::setUp ();
    $this->Category = new Category(0, $mdb2);

}

protected function tearDown() {
    $this->Category = null;
    parent::tearDown ();
}

public function __construct() {

}

public function test__construct() {

    $this->markTestIncomplete ( "__construct test not implemented" );

    $cat = $this->Category->__construct(0, $mdb2);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Category', $cat);
}

public function testReturnID() {

    $this->markTestIncomplete ( "returnID test not implemented" );

    $id = $this->Category->returnID();

    $this->assertEquals(0, $id);

}
  ...
}
```

Variable `$mdb2` comes from the db_connect.php file.

**I figured it out. The problem was that I included a variable from outside of a class.**

Comment: Can you show us some code? Like your php test class or the class tested so we can help and see the type error

Comment: Check for error.log in /var/log file. `tail -f /var/log/error.log` on sytem or in rule another for site.

Comment: Just added some code. And I ran `tail -f /var/log/error.log` but there was no such file

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite the `__construct()` method in your TestCase. The constructor sets up the mock generator, so you get a lot of strange behaviour and unwanted side effects if you overwrite the constructor. The `setUp()` method is the special method you should use to initialize your test.

Comment: Thanks for advice, it was behaving strangely.

Comment: @BramGerritsen That sounds like an answer (the answer), not a comment ;-)

Comment: @Darren Cook, you are right ;). Thanks for pointing me at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't overwrite the __construct() method in your TestCase. The constructor sets up the mock generator and some other mandatory thing for the test, so you get a lot of strange behaviour and unwanted side effects if you overwrite the constructor. The setUp() method is the special method you should use to initialize your test.